# Related Rates/ Optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

I was having trouble figuring out this problem.

A fisherman is in a boat 3 km from the nearest point A on the coast. The fisherman wishes
to return to his camp C located 5 km from the point A. The fishermen can row 4 km/hour
and he can walk 5 km/hour. To what point B, between A and C, should the fisherman row
to and then walk from B to the camp in order to reach the camp in the shortest time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, here, that point $C$ is on the shore, and that the shoreline is straight. Otherwise, this answer will not work.

Let $x$ be the distance (in kilometers) from point $B$ to point $C.$ Observe that $x$ is no greater than $5$ and no less than $0.$ (Why?) How much time will it take to get from $B$ to $C$ if the man is walking at $5$ kilometers per hour?

Now, note that from the boat's starting point (I'll call it $P$) it is $3$ kilometers to $A$, and from $A$ it is $5-x$ kilometers to $B.$ Using Pythagorean Theorem, how far is it from $P$ to $B$? (Draw a picture if you aren't sure.) How long will it take to get from $P$ to $B$ if the man is rowing at $4$ kilometers per hour?

How long will it take to get from $P$ to $B$ and then from $B$ to $C$? Can you take it from there?

Comment: I got a little lost after the Pythagorean Theorem part to be honest. First of all, I don't know how to get how long it would take from A to B and B to C and secondly, shouldn't it be the distance from the boat to B and B to C?

Comment: Oops! I managed to goof on what $A$ meant--the downside of not drawing a picture! I will amend my answer.

Comment: Answer amended. Have you drawn a picture that includes the boat's starting point (which I call $P$), the point $A$, and the point $B$? Do you see the right triangle?

Comment: Yes. I found the length of PB so am I supposed to differentiate it to find the length of time?

Comment: No. How are distance traveled ($d$), travel time ($t$), and speed of travel ($s$) related?

Comment: distance = speed * time?

Comment: Indeed! So time = ?

Comment: distance * speed. So multiply speed which is 4 by distance which is PB?

Comment: Not distance * speed, no. Let's rewrite the verbal equation as $d=st.$ Solve for $t.$

Comment: Sorry meant distance/speed

Comment: Yes! There we go. So, take the distance $PB$ and divide by $4$ to get the time (in hours) that it takes to get from $P$ to $B.$ Similarly, we find that it takes $\frac x5$ hours to get from $B$ to $C.$ So, you should be able to get a travel time function $T(x).$

Comment: Okay. And then do I differentiate T(x)?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Out of curiosity, what did you come up with for $T(x)$?

Comment: T(x) = sqrt(x^2 - 10x + 34)/4 + x/5 ?

Comment: That's it! Let me know if you have any more trouble with this, and I'll try to get you unstuck when I can.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the help.